# WIFI hidden networks and possible channel conflicts

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have been experiencing untimely WIFI bandwidth drops (down to zero bits/sec) . To be more precise, the connection itself is not dropped, just the ability to send and receive packets disappears for several seconds or minutes.

Thanks to [this posting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237777/is-there-a-tool-like-wifi-analyzer-for-ubuntu) I identified a couple of useful tools:

```
$ nmcli d wifi

IN-USE  BSSID              SSID           MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        A2:63:91:00:EC:D4  --             Infra  12    270 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2 
*       A0:63:91:00:EC:D4  Outernet       Infra  12    270 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2      
        FA:8F:CA:5D:D4:2C  --             Infra  6     65 Mbit/s   94      ▂▄▆█  --        
        A0:63:91:00:ED:8C  Outernet       Infra  2     270 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        30:D3:2D:9E:2A:9D  MOVISTAR_7E16  Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        08:40:F3:06:9E:09  COPITO         Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
        48:8D:36:34:9A:73  Outernet       Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
```

From this output, it appears that there is a conflict on channel 12. Outernet (A0:63:91:00:EC:D4) is indeed my router but I am struggling to find the ghost router on A2:63:91:00:EC:D4. Indeed I find it remarkably strange that it would have almost the same "MAC" address (only one character differs)

By using a WIFI analyzer I tried to check the signal strength and possibly locate said router. The issue, as can be seen in the screenshot, is that router on address A2:63:91:00:EC:D4 is not seen anywhere.

Hence, should I worry about this ghost router? If not, what else could be affecting my bandwidth randomly?

One more thing: this is not a problem with the WIFI card or driver as all devices at home are affected: Android phones, iOS phones, Windows laptop, Linux desktop and iPad.

[Android WIFI Analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJjnI.jpg)

**Update 14:23 CET**

I had to repost here as it was unwelcome [over there](https://serverfault.com/questions/1083503/wifi-hidden-networks-and-possible-channel-conflicts?noredirect=1#comment1414412_1083503)

Useful comment from Nikita:

> 7th bit 1 in the MAC address means "local" address. The only distinction between 1st and 2nd addresses is this bit. // The real problem in WiFi is not when all networks use the same channel, but when they use nearby overlapping channels. Here I see 11 and 12, 6 and 2 — in those pairs each will disrupt other one. But this shouldn't look like complete extended outage, but rather as noticeable slowdown. // You need to know SNR in addition to signal strength, and compare all of this when it works and during outage

1. It would be nice if someone could point to a document that explains which pairs of channels may disrupt each other
2. Also, why on earth do we need a "local" address? Only one of my routers has such local address.

Further steps I took since I originally redacted this question:

1. Changed the SSID of my routers and WIFI passwords
2. Updated firmware of my routers
3. Set one router to lock on to channel 4 and the second on to channel 5

So far so good but I am watching.

Comment: This page explains which channels do and don't overlap and why https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/why-channels-1-6-11/

Comment: Many routers can automagically select the best channel. (It may change over time)

Comment: Is your router 2.4 or 5 GHz? Which model is it? Do you have any wifi repeaters in the house?

Answer (score 0):

> It would be nice if someone could point to a document that explains which pairs of channels may disrupt each other

For 2.4 GHz band, literally every single diagram that Google finds for "[wifi channels](https://www.google.com/search?q=wifi+channels&source=lnms&tbm=isch)" will show you that.

For 5 GHz band, channels have been allocated such that they do not overlap.

> Outernet (A0:63:91:00:EC:D4) is indeed my router but I am struggling to find the ghost router on A2:63:91:00:EC:D4. Indeed I find it remarkably strange that it would have almost the same "MAC" address (only one character differs)

It's the same router. (Same channel, same signal strength, same physical rate.)

Most likely it serves an additional hidden SSID for internal purposes, e.g. automatic mesh connection between multiple Netgear routers (at least Huawei has such a mode, automatically turning additional routers into bridges/APs).

Usually each SSID needs its own MAC address. When the same Access Point supports serving multiple SSIDs, it will need to have multiple MAC addresses assigned out of the range that the manufacturer has purchased.

Sometimes the manufacturer assigns 2 or 3 addresses per device, but it's a limited resource and they might not want to "waste" assignments (don't forget that the Ethernet port needs its own MAC address too, etc.).

So in many cases, they only assign one MAC address from the "official" pool and that will be used for the "primary" SSID, while additional MACs are automatically generated by the device from the "local" or "private-use" range.

> Also, why on earth do we need a "local" address? Only one of my routers has such local address.

In general – same reason why "we" need local IP addresses. It's the MAC address equivalent of `192.168.x.x` or `10.x.x.x` or `fdxx::xxx` IP addresses – e.g. if you need 50 MAC addresses for 50 virtual machines, you can use 'local' addresses for free.

When used by the manufacturer, it's a cheap way to get extra MAC addresses for additional SSIDs. (In theory, there's no way to guarantee uniqueness of "local" addresses, but with 46 bits the chance of collisions is fairly low.)